# Getting Warning: Cannot modify header information on GoDaddy but not Wamp

Tags: php, webserver

I am getting the `Warning: Cannot modify header information`. I am NOT getting this error when testing the source code on WAMP. Also in some of the PHP certain classes are included and functions to manipulate the html are called as needed. Can any one point me in the right direction? Here's the exact error and the cited files.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/content/39/8810539/html/pagoda/view/header.php:2) in
>   /home/content/39/8810539/html/pagoda/controller/login.php on line 9

login.php:

```
<?php

    global $session;
    global $view;

    if (isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        if ($session->logIn($_POST["uname"],$_POST["password"]))
            header("Location: $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
        else
            $view->RenderMsg("Your username and/or password was incorrect.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['logout']))
    {
        $session->logOut();
        header("Location: $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"); 
    }


?>
```

header.php snippet:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo BASEPATH; ?>/view/css/homepageStyle.css" />
</head>
<div id="header">
    <div id="banner">
        Pagoda
    </div>
    <div id="login">

<?php 

    //This controls the login/logout header on the top of each page.

    global $session;
    if ($session->isLoggedIn())
    {
?>
    <div id="nametag">
        <form method="POST" name="logout" action="">
        Welcome, <?php echo $session->getName()." (".$session->getRole().")"?>
        <input name="logout" type="hidden" value="Log Out"/>
        </form>
    </div>  
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: You may be having empty space before `<?php`, also immediately after `header()` use `exit;`

Comment: A bit tongue-in-cheek here, but if I were you my first order of business would be changing away from the awful GoDaddy hosting service.

Comment: Please remove trailing spaces in php file.

Comment: It is not(!) a problem of Godaddy, it is a problem of your code and settings of WAMP not showing you warning messages or enabling ob as default. Your output already started at `header.php` (which is obvious as you started the file with output of the html code). It means that you CAN NOT send any headers after that (when your `headers.php` is executed). Only if you enable output buffering as a default setting or start it somewhere else before the header.php is included into main script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with ob_start(). ob_start writes the html to a buffer first, then it writes it to the browser after the header has changed. ob_start goes before your html code. It's not necessary but good practice to close the buffer after the header() with ob_end_flush();

header.php snippet:

```
<?php
     ob_start()
 ?>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo BASEPATH; ?>/view/css/homepageStyle.css" />
</head>
<div id="header">
    <div id="banner">
        Pagoda
    </div>
    <div id="login">

<?php 

    //This controls the login/logout header on the top of each page.

    global $session;
    if ($session->isLoggedIn())
    {
?>
    <div id="nametag">
        <form method="POST" name="logout" action="">
        Welcome, <?php echo $session->getName()." (".$session->getRole().")"?>
        <input name="logout" type="hidden" value="Log Out"/>
        </form>
    </div>  
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

login.php

```
<?php

    global $session;
    global $view;

    if (isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        if ($session->logIn($_POST["uname"],$_POST["password"]))
            header("Location: $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
            ob_end_flush();
        else
            $view->RenderMsg("Your username and/or password was incorrect.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['logout']))
    {
        $session->logOut();
        header("Location: $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
        ob_end_flush(); 
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW some errors in your code:

1) Do not use "?>", or you will receive the same warning if you will have spaces at the end of the files(some editors do it)

2) You forgot HTML escaping in "<?php echo $session->getName()...": use htmlspecialchars()

3) Do not use globals. Never.

4) Logic and view should be separated.

Comment: I think just dropping the `?>` from `login.php` might just fix your issue.  Apparently there is a space at the end of that file and removing `?>` an acceptable solution.

Comment: Does "Do not use globals. Never." mean you code web apps entirely without `$_POST` and `$_GET` and `$_SERVER`? Or is that the meme about avoiding language features at *all* costs and specifically where they would make sense?